# looping through dictionary built from csv and write certain key values to file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to open a file and read it into a dictionary. I've done this successfully, but I need to write the 'values' to variable and then take the variable and write it to another file in a certain location. Or is there a way to not putting them all into a variable.

The 'person1' in the write section is what I need to do, but for the multiple names in the file.

I am a noob so I apologize if I am confusing.

Link to data file [DataFileLayout](http://i.imgur.com/OcZ1tlK.jpg)

```
`import csv
with open('registrant_data.csv') as csvFile:
    readCSV = list(csv.DictReader(csvFile))
    for row in readCSV:
        person1 = row['firstname'] + ' ' + row['lastname']


# HTML Top of page

with open('nametags8gen.html', 'w+') as myWriteFile:
    myWriteFile.write('<!DOCTYPE html> \n'
                      '<html>\n'
                      '<head>\n'
                      '<title>natetag8</title>\n'
                      '<link href="styles/nametags8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />\n'
                      '</head>\n'
                      '<body>\n'
                      '<header>\n'
                      '</header>\n'
                      '<main class="mainContainer">\n'
                      '<div class"textBoxContainer">\n'
                      '<div class="textContainer">\n'
                      '<span class="font22">' + person1 +'</span>\n'
                      '<span class="font12">Smith</span>\n'
                      '<span class="font14">Web Developer</span>\n'
                      '<span class="font12">Regis University</span>\n'
                      '<span class="font12">Denver, CO</span>\n'
                      '</div>\n')
    csvFile.close()`
```

Comment: Do you need to write one html file per person?

Comment: Note that the `csvFile.close()` might cause problems. Because it's a "context manager" it will already have been automatically closed at the end of the `with` grouping.

Comment: I will have multiple areas like the on there. I will be filling in all of the hard coded information with info from the csv file.

Comment: ok I will get rid of the close, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your desired output is. What about this? In this code, I first write the beginning of the html file, then I loop through the csv file and add a few spans for each row of the file.

```
import csv

with open('registrant_data.csv') as csvFile:
    readCSV = list(csv.DictReader(csvFile))

with open('nametags8gen.html', 'w+') as myWriteFile:
    myWriteFile.write('<!DOCTYPE html> \n'
                      '<html>\n'
                      '<head>\n'
                      '<title>natetag8</title>\n'
                      '<link href="styles/nametags8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />\n'
                      '</head>\n'
                      '<body>\n'
                      '<header>\n'
                      '</header>\n'
                      '<main class="mainContainer">\n'
                      '<div class"textBoxContainer">\n'
                      '<div class="textContainer">\n')


    for row in readCSV:
        myWriteFile.write('<span class="font22">' + row['firstname'] +'</span>\n'
                          '<span class="font12">' + row['lastname'] +'</span>\n'
        # here add other info for each person

    myWriteFile.write('</div>\n'
                      '</body>\n')
```

Comment: I need to give more context. We are tasked with making a 8 up template of nametags in html and some css formatting. Then we were given a csv file that lists peoples information. I need to pull the certain pieces of data like "Firstname and Lastname" and then put them into the hard coded spots and have it substitute in the values from the csv. Sorry for the lack of info