# Python: Print specific value from a dictionary list that was read from a csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to know how to read a csv file into a dictionary and then print out a specific value from the dictionary with python. [CSV file example](http://i.imgur.com/OcZ1tlK.jpg). I'd like to grab the line that is selected and print that persons name out. I'm new at this and I've tried some loops, but the loop goes right past to the last person.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as csvFile:
readCSV = list(csv.DictReader(csvFile))
for row in readCSV:
    person1 = row['firstname'] + ' ' + row['lastname']
with open('nametags8gen.html', 'w+') as myWriteFile:
myWriteFile.write('<!DOCTYPE html> \n'
                  '<html>\n'
                  '<head>\n'
                  '<title>natetag8</title>\n'
                  '<link href="styles/nametags8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />\n'
                  '</head>\n'
                  '<body>\n'
                  '<header>\n'
                  '</header>\n'
                  '<main class="mainContainer">\n'
                  '<div class"textBoxContainer">\n'
                  '<div class="textContainer">\n'
                  '<span class="font22">' + person1 +'</span>\n'
                  '<span class="font12">Smith</span>\n'
                  '<span class="font14">Web Developer</span>\n'
                  '<span class="font12">Regis University</span>\n'
                  '<span class="font12">Denver, CO</span>\n'
                  '</div>\n')
```

This loops through and grabs the last person and not the specific person I need.

The 'write' section is where I will be putting the persons information, specifically in that spot that says 'person1' in my html template is where a first and last name will go that I take from the CSV file. I don't know how to make the loop stop on a certain person/row to pull their information, such as firstname or their address.

Comment: Add the code you have attempted to use if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748931/looping-through-dictionary-built-from-csv-and-write-certain-key-values-to-file ?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like :

```
import csv
l = []

with open('inputfile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        l.append(row)

# If you need say for example the firstname
for val in l:
    print (l['firstname'])
```

Although its still unclear without the code what exactly are you trying to achieve.